# Why does setting a DataSet row value to Nothing initialize it to the data type minvalue?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

When setting a DataSet row column to `Nothing`, like `row.Date = Nothing`, why does it initialize it to the data type minvalue? In this case a date, that gets set to `0000-01-01`. The column is set to allow null etc., and if I don't set the row to anything at all, it will leave the column empty. So why does `Nothing` act this way?

In C# I would've set it to `DbNull`, I guess, but I'm a tad green on VB.NET - as you might be able to tell. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hps is correct that you should use `DBNull.Value` to assign a `NULL` value to a database column.

```
  row.Date = DBNull.Value
```

The reason you see the a default value being set is that the keyword `Nothing` in VB.NET is comparable to `default(T)` in C#, not C#'s `null` keyword.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for clearing that up! I've always thought Nothing was the same as NULL. I really miss programming in C#. :/

Comment: I can't use System.DBNull for the date though - "Value of type System.DBNull cannot be converted to Date".

Comment: I believe it works in the same way in both VB.Net and C#. Even if in C# you try to assign a "null" value (= null) to a Column of type DateTime it will throw exception. And equivalent of default(T) in VB.Net would more like be CType(Nothing, T). Nothing in VB.Net and null in C# are more like each other.

Comment: @Hps - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28VS.80%29.aspx) pretty clearly states that `Nothing` sets a variable to its default value.

Comment: Yes Phil, You are correct, that while assigning Nothing to value types these are initialized to the default values. Probably it is just an extra feature that VB.Net compiler allows to take advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be able to set DBNull in VB.Net as well something like

```
table.Rows(0)(0) = System.DBNull.Value
```

or `row.Date = System.DBNull.Value`

For assigning the "Nothing", you will need to have Nullable Type